# fluent-nhibernate cascade delete to collection of joined-subclassess

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, cascading-deletes

New user to fluent nhibernate here and I have a model with a parent class that holds a collection of subclassed children (using TablePerSubClass inheritance). When attempting to to test cascading deletes by calling delete only on the parent object I get a constraint error between the child table and its joined-subclass table. To demonstrate...

```
    public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent> {
        public ParentMap() {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
                .Inverse();
        }
    }

    public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child> {
        public ChildMap() {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            References(x => x.Parent).Not.Nullable();
        }
    }

    public class ExtendedChildMap : SubclassMap<ExtendedChild> {
        public ExtendedChildMap() {
            Map(x => x.extraFeature);
        }
    }
```

When unit testing with the following code...

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {

        var p = new Parent();
        var c1 = new Child() { Parent = p };
        var c2 = new ExtendedChild() { Parent = p };

        session.SaveOrUpdate(p);
        session.SaveOrUpdate(c1);
        session.SaveOrUpdate(c2);
        Assert.IsTrue(session.Query<Parent>().Count() == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(session.Query<Child>().Count() == 2);
        Assert.IsTrue(session.Query<ExtendedChild>().Count() == 1);

        session.Delete(p);
        Assert.IsTrue(session.Query<Parent>().Count() == 0);
    }
}
```

The test fails on the final assertion with

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FKDB46742824B330ED". The conflict occurred in database "testDB", table "dbo.ExtendedChild", column 'Child_id'
```

If the collection only holds the baseclass Child objects it works as expected, but when a derived ExtendedChild is added the delete doesn't seem to propogate to the baseclass. Feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I've still not managed to solve this after a good while searching.

Lastly, I'm also still not 100% clear on the functional differences between `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan` and `ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete`... or more precisely (ignoring the save/update part) what is the case that the former doesn't handle and requires the latter to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with reference constraint is related to the fact, that we do not properly set the *parent-child* relation.

I. Not only child should/must know about the parent, but also parent must be informed about its children:

```
var p = new Parent();
// assign parent to children
var c1 = new Child() { Parent = p };
var c2 = new ExtendedChild() { Parent = p };
// assign children to parent as well
p.Children.Add(c1);
p.Children.Add(c2);
```

The above code and the mapping with cascade is enough for NHibernate to call just:

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(p);
```

and Parent `p`, Child `c1` and ExtendedChild `c2` ... all will be persisted.

And if we are inside of **one** continues *session*, the existing instance of parent `p`, can be deleted:

```
session.Delete(p)
```

and that will also trigger deletion of all the children - because parent does know about them: *and call the cascade for them*...

II. The cascading must be driven by NHibernate only - not by DB.

We also have to remove the **`ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete`** which effectively does create the DB script with a SQL Server native cascading... this is not needed - in this case.

```
HasMany(x => x.Children)
    ...
    // good and very helpful setting Cascade
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()

    // this is not what we want
    // we do not need cascade on SQL Server side
    // .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
```

Unit testing:

The best way, how to make the above test fully working is to split creation and deletion. To do that, we should issue:

- `Flush()` to be sure that the session does persist all the changes
- `Clear()` to start with a new clean table

the structure could look like this:

```
// as above... create Parent and Children - assign each to other
// and call parent to save
session.SaveOrUpdate(p);

// now we have to be sure, that the session will propagate 
// all the changes into the DB
session.Flush();

// and reset all the settings:
session.Clear();

// now (re)load the parent to later let NHiberante do the correct cascade
var parentReloaded = session.Get<Parent>(p.Id);

// Delete all the related stuff
session.Delete(parentReloaded);
```

In case, that the constraint is related to our newly created children, this will do the job....

Comment: Thanks for posting. I mistakenly thought the current instance of p would get the references to the children after the SaveOrUpdate() (similar to how nhibernate changes the ID field after the object is persisted) but having gone through with the debugger I see now that isn't the case. I made the changes you suggested and explicitly added the children to the parent's collection before saving but I STILL get the same error... I'm keen to figure out how to get this unit test to work within a single transaction and confirm the deletes are being cascaded.

Comment: I updated my answer with a draft of steps needed to succeed inside of your unit test. That should work, if the exception, the constraint is really related to the child - parent realtion. BUT it seems, that the real problem is in your hierarchy mapping. Because the blaming is the 'child_id' column of the ExtenededChild table. Not sure what that constraint does...

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid. The delete works as expected if I commit first and then call delete() in a new session but calling it from the original transaction seems to still trip on the FK between Child and ExtendedChild. [HERE is a picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GnKml.png) of what ManagementStudio shows for the database keys.

Comment: I see that clearly... wrong cascading of the subclass... BUT there is a SQL Server cascade setting (Delete rule: cascade) on the first constraint. Could you remove that? Because that could be casuing (I am almost sure) that foreign key violation. Leave it only on NHibernate... no DB cascade

Comment: THANK YOU. The test finally passed. Made the same amendments to my actual application and it worked a treat (without any intermediate calls to Flush or Clear). If you'd like to edit your answer with A) adding the children to the parent collection and B) removing `ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete` I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Great to see that, I adjsuted the answer to summarize both issues. So glad to see another "more happy NHibernate user" ;) Enjoy NHibernate ;)